# ')' expected error .... Can't figure this out

Tags: java

I'm getting the compilation error: `')' expected error` and yet as you may see in my code below there are not any unbalanced parenthesis. What could it be.

Here's my code for an assignment at school:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment7b {


public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException {

  ArrayMath A = new ArrayMath();

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
    String fileName = console.next();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    int[][] matrixA = makeMatrix(input);
    int[][] matrixB = makeMatrix(input);
    int[][] matrixC = makeMatrix(input);
    int[][] matrixD = makeMatrix(input);
    int[][] addResult = A.addArrays(matrixA, matrixB);
    int[][] subResult = A.subArrays(matrixA, matrixB);
    int[][] multResult = A.multArrays(matrixC, matrixD);
    System.out.print("Output file name: ");
    String outputFile = console.next();
    output(outputFile, matrixA, matrixB, matrixC, matrixD, addResult, subResult, multResult);

}

public static int[][] makeMatrix(Scanner input) {
    int rows = input.nextInt();
    int col = input.nextInt();
    int[][] thisMatrix = new int[rows][col];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        input.nextLine();
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            int num = input.nextInt();
            thisMatrix[i][j]++;             
        }
   }
    return thisMatrix;
}

public static void output(String outputFile, int[][] matrixA, int[][] matrixB, int[][] matrixC, int[][] matrixD, int[][] addResult, int[][] subResult, int[][] multResult) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new File(outputFile));
    ArrayMath A = new ArrayMath();    
    out.print("MATRIX A: /n");
    out.print(A.2dArrayText(matrixA));
    out.print("MATRIX B: /n");
    out.print(A.2dArrayText(matrixB));
    out.print("A PLUS B: /n");
    out.print(A.2dArrayText(addResult));
    out.print("A MINUS B: \n");
    out.print(A.2dArrayText(subResult));
    out.print("MATRIX C: \n");
    out.print(A.2dArrayText(matrixC));
    out.print("MATRIX D: \n");
    out.print(A.print2dArray(matrixD));
    out.print("C TIMES D: \n");
    out.print(A.2dArrayText(multResult));

}

}
```

I'm getting an error on all my out.print() lines. I've checked everywhere and don't see an unbalanced parentheses, yet I continue to get the errors like

```
Assignment7b.java:47: ')' expected
```

I've Googled the issue and can't figure it out, so I'm consulting the experts at Stack Overflow. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: ok which line is 47 and why did you not just add a )

Comment: @BevynQ it's the first out.print() one. Same error for all the out.print() lines.

Comment: Doesn't your `int[][] thisMatrix = new int[rows][col];` line require parentheses as part of the construction?

Comment: I edited the question to add clarity. This is actually a good question.

Comment: Where did you get your ArrayMath class from?

Answer (score 10):

You CANNOT have a method name starting with a number, as in `2dArrayText`. That will confuse the compiler.

Comment: At last ... a sensible theory!

Comment: "A.2dArrayText" will be parsed as `<identifier> '.' <integer> <identifier>` which will seriously confuse the syntax checker.

Comment: @user2684794 Mark this answer as acepted

Answer (score 1):

Repro

```
class X {
    void y() {
        System.out.println( A.1d());
    }
}

javac X.java
X.java:3: error: ')' expected
    System.out.println( A.1d());
                         ^
```

Answer, don't use a number as first character of an identifier.